# Bing API in .net

Tags: c#, .net, bing, bing-api

I use this code to use bing api in my app:

```
string requestString = "http://api.bing.net/xml.aspx?"

        // Common request fields (required)
        + "AppId=" + bingAppId
        + "&Query=" + searchString
        + "&Sources=Web"
        + "&Web.Count=20";
```

and i want to know if there is a way to tell the api that i dont want to get results from a specific website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in query: `-site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

Bing API can support scoping results, from only select websites (using Bing Custom Search API). But I doubt it will let you omit a website.